# Need help finding a regex pattern for extracting a data from a data string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the phone number and full name from a data string, but I can't figure out a regex pattern needed for extracting the said data. Can anyone help me with it?

This is the data string:

> Sat, September 3rd, 10:13am - Case Lead ID: #C69-660-301C
>
> John Doe | user@xyz.com | 5551234567

FYI, I found a regex pattern to extract email and it worked.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

BTW, the tool I use to extract this data only supports positive lookahead regex patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is always structured like this on a single line with 2 pipes, you can use a negated character class with 3 capture groups.

Assuming there are no pipes in the data, and the delimiter is fixed like  `|`

```
^([^|\n]+) \| ([^|\n]+) \| ([^|\n]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NnwS0u/1)

Or a bit more specific matching an email like pattern and 10 digits in the last part:

```
^([^|\n]+) \| ([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+) \| (\d+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAJ4IA/1)

Comment: Hey, le me try that.

Actually the said data is structured in single line but it is inside a big string of data,

Comment: @fahadsheji You could also try it without the anchors `([^|\n]+) \| ([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+) \| (\d+)`

Comment: Okay. FYI, I took a screenshot of the data string for a better understanding on where the data lies inside the string, here it is:https://imgur.com/a/bmo5XMc

Comment: Hey, the one without anchors worked, thanks mate

Comment: Hey one other question, I also wanted to extract a data from this string

"** Case Description:
- help with the paperwork"

The regex pattern I used is this
Case Description:\n(.+)

It didn't work, could you tell me what I did wrong here

Comment: @fahadsheji It depends, you are matching a newline which might not be there. Try it like this `Case Description:\s(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/XgzCjD/1 or `Case Description:\s*-\s*(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/46y2qL/1

Answer (score 0):

For a phone number:

```
\d{10} # will match 10 digits
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} # will match a ten digit phone number with dashes
```

For a full name, assuming the first letters of the first and last name are capitalized and that there is a single space between the names, which is not always the case:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\ [A-Z][a-z]+
```

If there are other number formats that you may need, or names that have punctuation, accent marks, or initials, I can amend my answer.

In case it is helpful, this is the website that I use for practicing Regex: https://regexr.com/